# Wordpress - Allow showing same posts multiple times in one loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

I got an array of Post Ids

```
$ids = array(1277,6098,6709, 6098);
```

I want to loop throw these specific posts with:

```
$args = array(   'orderby' => 'post__in',
                    'post__in' => $ids);

get_posts($args);
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $custom_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    the_title();
    ...
endforeach;
```

But wordpress automatically excludes the repeated Id (6098). How can I avoid this?

---

I tryed to create my own function. But unfortunately it doesnt work. I created my own get_posts function like this:

```
function get_posts_jt($args = null) {
                $defaults = array(
                    'numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0,
                    'category' => 0, 'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'order' => 'DESC', 'include' => array(),
                    'exclude' => array(), 'meta_key' => '',
                    'meta_value' =>'', 'post_type' => 'post',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
                );

                $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
                if ( empty( $r['post_status'] ) )
                    $r['post_status'] = ( 'attachment' == $r['post_type'] ) ? 'inherit' : 'publish';
                if ( ! empty($r['numberposts']) && empty($r['posts_per_page']) )
                    $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];
                if ( ! empty($r['category']) )
                    $r['cat'] = $r['category'];
                if ( ! empty($r['include']) ) {
                    $incposts = $r['include'];
                    $r['posts_per_page'] = count($incposts);  // only the number of posts included
                    $r['post__in'] = $incposts;
                } elseif ( ! empty($r['exclude']) )
                    $r['post__not_in'] = wp_parse_id_list( $r['exclude'] );

                $r['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;
                $r['no_found_rows'] = true;

                $get_posts = new WP_Query;
                return $get_posts->query($r);

            }
```

I changed the line from:

```
$incposts = wp_parse_id_list( $r['include'] );
```

to:

```
$incposts = $r['include'];
```

to avoid removing duplicated Ids from array. But this function still doesnt show the duplicated posts from my Id List.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop your ids and call `get_post` with `setup_postdata` :

```
global $post;
foreach ($ids as $id) :
    $post = get_post($id);
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
endforeach;
```

Comment: this is an old post, but yeah this is a solution for this problem, dont know why this has not come into my mind :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't: `get_posts` uses [`wp_parse_id_list`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L2550) to remove duplicate ids from the supplied array.

Comment: You could roll your own functions (e.g. `my_get_posts` and `my_wp_parse_id_list`)